# Aligning and nesting divs (CSS layout trouble)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve the following layout:
[image]

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content1">
        <span>Content1</span>
        <div id="text">
            <span>Text</span>
        </div>
        <div id="game">
            <span>Game</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
        <span>Content2</span>
        <div id="gallery">
            <span>Gallery</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <span>Footer</span>
</div>
```

The middle part is contained in main div. The left part is content 1 and the right part is content2. Content1 is split into two parts (nested divs). I am struggling with this easy task for hours.. Things I'm trying to do, but having trouble with:

- I want this website to take 100% of browser width
- I was able to split content1 and content2 and fit them into the same line, but when I added borders I couldn't align them anymore (I tried overflow: hidden;, display: inline-block;, and flex display but somehow I couldn't get it to work..)
- Center the elements in content2 (is it enough if I use margin: auto?)
  I'm also wondering if the HTML layout I posted is OK, since I don't know how much is nesting welcomed? Or is nesting usually used for containers and such? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with nested `Flexbox`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.one {
  flex: 2;
}
.two {
  flex: 1;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
header,
footer {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="one">One</div>
      <div class="two">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I hope I'll be able to type this up as quick as you did soon. One question.. I keep seeing classes instead of id's in a lot of SO examples. are they somehow superior, or is is just personal preference?

Comment: I prefer classes. Here is https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/434/ if you want to modify something.